# How do non administrators add content?

Tags: users, nodes

In Drupal 7, how do I let the users with a specific role add new articles?

I logged in as administrator, set the permission for the role to allow creating and editing nodes that are articles.
When I login with a user with the role, for example, "NewRole," I do not see any control or dashboard that allows me to create new articles.

How do I start adding new articles as this new user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You probably don't have the Navigation menu enabled/placed in a region, or have any other links to direct a user to the Create Content page.

As an administrator, either enable that menu or create a link to "node/add" (to allow the users to see all the content types for which they can create a node); you can also add a  link to "node/add/article" in another menu or in your theme.

To allow a user to see the administration toolbar, they must have a role that has the permission to use the administration toolbar. See below:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: awesome....so for ANY user, you can go to `http://mysite.com/node/add` to add any content type.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Yes, any user that goes to example.com/node/add will see all the content types they can create in a list, then click on a link and see the node form.

Comment: I followed this but still get "Error
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." when the user follows link

Answer (score 3):

You must set the right permission! Now i give to you a screenshot
[image]

[image]

If you set the permission for example as the screenshot the user will modify article type content.

Comment: Sorry, see the Laxman13's response, i dont read well your answer

Comment: Hey Giovanni, I tried your settings and the black Admin Dashboard still doesn't show up for users with MyRole

Comment: @John if you mean the toolbar across the top that has administrative links, in order for a user to see it, they must have a role that has the permission "Use the administration toolbar".  See the edit in my answer for the picture example